# Nested unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, unnamed-namespace

When using an unnamed namespace are there any issues if it is nested within another namespace?  For example, is there any real difference between Foo1.cpp and Foo2.cpp in the following code:

```
// Foo.h
namespace Foo
{
    void fooFunc();
}

// Foo1.cpp
namespace Foo
{
    namespace
    {
        void privateFunction()
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    void fooFunc()
    {
        privateFunction();
    }
}

// Foo2.cpp
namespace
{
    void privateFunction()
    {
        ...
    }
}

namespace Foo
{
    void fooFunc()
    {
        privateFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exported symbols will be different. Take a look a nm output.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, the technical term is `unnamed namespace`, not anonymous.

Comment: Unions are anonymous, namespace are unnamed. But who cares :)

Comment: While the term is `unnamed`, if you check with `nm` or `gdb` under  the tools will call it `anonymous namespace`, so the confusion is understandable.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unnamed namespace could be considered as a normal namespace with unique name which you do not know. According to C++ Standard 7.3.1.1:

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by

```
  namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
  using namespace unique;
  namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

> 

where all occurrences of unique in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier and this identifier differs from all other identifiers in the entire program.

There are no additional issues.

Answer (score 4):

Probably no real difference for your purposes. It makes a difference to where in your cpp file `privateFunction` is visible. If you add `void barFunc() { privateFunction(); }` to the end of both files, then Foo2.cpp compiles and Foo1.cpp doesn't.

Normally you wouldn't define external symbols from lots of different namespaces in the same cpp file, so the difference won't come up.

Comment: "The end of both files" meaning "after the `namespace Foo {}` "?

Comment: @MikeC - Yes, I would say @SteveJessop means after `namespace Foo {}`