# Nesting unnamed namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is there a functional difference between these two nested usages of unnamed namespaces:

```
namespace A { namespace {
  void foo() {/*...*/}
}}
```

and

```
namespace { namespace A {
  void foo() {/*...*/}
}}
```

As far as I see it, both `foo`s will get an internal unique identifier per compilation unit and can be accessed with `A::foo` - but is there a subtle or not-so-subtle difference that I'm not seeing?

Comment: (edited) You can effectively hide the second `foo` by declaring another `A::foo` at the file level. The first `foo` will be always accessible as `::A::foo`. Unless you reopen `A` and declare another `foo` there. That is, yes, pretty much the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly as you typed, there is no difference.

You can, of course, add declarations in the first level of namespace to booth examples and then it will be a difference.

```
namespace A {
  int i;         // Accessed globally in this file as "A::i".
  namespace {
    void foo() {/*...*/}
}}


namespace {
  int i;         // Accessed globally in this file simply as "i".
  namespace A {
    void foo() {/*...*/}
}}}
```

Note that, although you programmer have no way to distinguish, for the compiler, the namespaces are distinct:

```
unnamed_namespaces.cpp:42:5: error: reference to ‘A’ is ambiguous
unnamed_namespaces.cpp:19:17: error: candidates are: namespace A { }
unnamed_namespaces.cpp:28:19: error:                 namespace <unnamed>::A { }
```

Usefull:

- [Nested anonymous namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094072/nested-anonymous-namespace)
- http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-namespaces-and-anonymous-namespaces
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Funnamed_namespaces.htm
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31783&seqNum=6
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yct4x9k5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

---

EDIT:

In respect to ADL (Argument-dependent name lookup), I understand that it will be no precedence difference in overload resolution for other `foo()` as below:

```
#include    <iostream>

void foo() { std::cout << "::foo()" << std::endl; }

namespace A {
    namespace {
        void foo() { std::cout << "A::<unnamed>::foo()" << std::endl; }

        class   AClass
        {
        public:
            AClass( )
            {   foo( ); }
        };
    }
}


namespace {
    namespace B {
        void foo() { std::cout << "B::<unnamed>::foo()" << std::endl; }

        using namespace A;

        class   BClass
        {
        public:
            BClass( )
            {   foo( ); }

            ~BClass( )
            {   A::foo( );  }
        };
    }
}

int main( )
{
    A::foo( );
    B::foo( );
    foo( );

    A::AClass   a;
    B::BClass   b;

    return  0;
}
```

Compiler will prefer the closest `foo( )` unless explicitly specified.
So `BClass` constructor calls `B::foo( )` even having a `using namespace A` on it.
To call `A::foo( )` on `BClass` destructor, the call must be explicitly qualified.

```
A::<unnamed>::foo()
B::<unnamed>::foo()
::foo()
A::<unnamed>::foo()
B::<unnamed>::foo()
A::<unnamed>::foo()
```

Maybe it become clearer if we think in nested *named* namespaces and how the argument-dependent will be solved. The olny difference will be an implicit `using` on the unnamed ones, but it won't change the compiler preference.

Comment: I think your access example is backwards. The first one is `A::i` and the second is just `i`.

Comment: While this is a superb answer so far, I was wondering what kinds of effects the namespaces can have on ADL - will `namespace A {void bar();}` be able able to find `foo ()` in any of the examples?